# Cannot convert bitmap to texture

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, loading, opentk

I'm doing a little C# / OpenGL project and I can't manage to load textures properly.

So here is my texture class :

```
public class Texture
{
   public String Filepath;
   private int TextureID;

   public Texture(byte[] Filename)
   {
        Stream s = FileManager.FindTexture(Filename);

        if (s == null) return;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(FileManager.FindTexture(Filename));

        b.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(255,0,255));

        //b = BitmapEx.Resize(b, b.Width * 2, b.Height * 2);

        //b.Save(DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString() + ".png");
        //GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

        GL.GenTextures(1, out TextureID);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureID);

        BitmapData data = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba8, data.Width, data.Height, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

        b.UnlockBits(data);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

        if(!GL.IsTexture(TextureID))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        if (TextureID != 0)
        {
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureID);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my bitmap loads well from the stream. I tried to save it after it loaded into a my debug folder and every texture loaded saves. So I'm pretty sure this part is not the problem. But everytime I try to do GL.IsTexture it returns false, I tried to apply my textures either it doesn't work.

I've used a similar method in another project where it was working.

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Data/UI/" + File);

        GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

        GL.GenTextures(1, out Texture);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, Texture);

        BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);


        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
```

I can't see why it is not working right now.

My textures are loaded way after OpenGL is initialized.

I'm using C# .NET framework 3.5 with OpenTK 1.1 ( Runtime 2.0.5, fresh out of their websites ).

Can someone give me a hint on why it is not working, please ?

Warm regards, Chaussette.

Comment: `glIsTexture` [is used](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glIsTexture.xhtml) to determine if the provided name is indeed a texture. It has nothing to do with whether the data inside is correct or not. In other words, `glIsTexture` is related to `glGenTextures` and `glBindTexture`, and has nothing to do with `glTexImage2D`. The correct place to check with `glIsTexture` would be right after `glBindTexture`. I've also had some trouble with `GL.GenTextures` in the past. How about using `GL.GenTexture` instead?

Comment: So I've tried to use `TextureID = GL.GenTexture();`, it didn't worked. I also tried to put my `GL.IsTexture` right after my `GL.GenTexture` and I still get my exception thrown. I put my `GL.IsTexture` in my old project and it worked fine. I've also tried using the same textures just in case the fileformat would be wrong but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: What value are you getting from `glGenTexture`?

Comment: The idea is that, if `glIsTexture` is returning `false`, then your culprit is not related at all with `glTexImage2D`. It has nothing to do with your data. There is some reason why you're not getting a valid texture name, and improperly initialized OpenGL comes to mind. You say you're initializing it properly though...

Comment: My `GL.GenTexture` returns me 1. OpenGL is initialized by OpenTK. It displays me polygons. Here's my OnLoad function `                game.Load += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    game.Title = "Test";
                    game.Icon = r.favicon;
                    game.VSync = VSyncMode.Off;

                    GL.ClearColor(Color.Lavender);
                    GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

                    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
                    GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
                };`

Comment: I don't have much to say. Even though I think that `glIsTexture` is meaningful only before `glImage2D`, I do want to point out that you're using `PixelInternalFormat.Rgba8`. I commonly use `PixelInternalFormat.Rgba`. How about trying `PixelInternalFormat.Rgba`?

Comment: I tried to use PixelInternalFormat.Rgba before, I thought it could be the problem so I tried with Rgba8 but it didn't helped :/. How about a little teamviewer session ? My ID is 439 674 347 the password is your steam username x*****.

Comment: I think I found a solution. My problem might that when I'm generating my list, I'm applying my textures, and if the texture doesn't not exist I try to load it, but I'm already in a GLBegin wich prevents me from doing the loading operations. I'll try this out and tell you if it working or not.

Comment: It seems to work ^_^ just having my textures overwriten by the last one loaded, but I'll figure a wait for this.

Comment: You may want to consider using a more modern OpenGL approach, with vertex buffers...

Comment: It looks indeed really powerfull, I'll give it a look pretty soon, just after I'll have my texture problem fixed x)

Comment: Not only more powerful but also easier. With VBO there is no glBegin or glEnd, so your current pronlem is inexistent